# Variable scope in function expressions

Tags: javascript, function

I've been learning some basics of JavaScript lately and have spent quite some time disassembling some function expressions to better understand them. I'm still a bit unsure what actually happens in the few examples and would like some explanation on it if I'm wrong, or at least confirmation whether my train of thought is correct.

There are three snippets of code with slight differences in them:

```
var my_number = 7;

var timesTwo = function(number) {
    my_number = number * 2;
    console.log("inside " + my_number);
};

timesTwo(5);
console.log("outside " + my_number);
```

.

```
var my_number = 7;

var timesTwo = function(number) {
    var my_number = number * 2;
    console.log("inside " + my_number);
};

timesTwo(5);
console.log("outside " + my_number);
```

.

```
var my_number = 7;

var timesTwo = function(my_number) {
    my_number = my_number * 2;
    console.log("inside " + my_number);
};

timesTwo(5);
console.log("outside " + my_number);
```

What I'm curious about is what exactly happens to make them work like they do.

The first case seems relatively straight forward - `my_number` starts as a global, `number` is local to the function and `my_number` is changed inside the function so it's 10 in global frame.

The second case also seems clear - it's similar to the first one, only there is a new local variable `my_number` inside the function that is assigned 10, and outside the function `my_number` is still 7.

What I am unsure about is the third piece. I assume that since all mentions of `number` is now `my_number`, the function creates a new `my_number` variable in the following line:

```
var timesTwo = function(my_number)
```

even though there is no `var my_number` in the function body?

Comment: that is correct, and this question can basically be unasked =) All function arguments are function-scoped variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var my_number = 7;

var timesTwo = function(number) {
    my_number = number * 2;
    console.log("inside " + my_number);
};

timesTwo(5);
console.log("outside " + my_number);
```

This first example declares `my_number` in the global scope and sets its value to `7`. `timesTwo` is a function that accepts an argument in its parameter, which is then referenced to as `number` within the function. When the function is called, you are setting the `my_number` variable defined in the global scope to be equal to the passed in argument multiplied by two. You are logging the same result with both the "inside" and "outside" calls.

```
var my_number = 7;

var timesTwo = function(number) {
    var my_number = number * 2;
    console.log("inside " + my_number);
};

timesTwo(5);
console.log("outside " + my_number);
```

In this second example, you are declaring a locally scoped `my_number` within the `timesTwo` function. Because of this, you are logging different `my_number` variables in your "inside" and "outside" calls.

```
var my_number = 7;

var timesTwo = function(my_number) {
    my_number = my_number * 2;
    console.log("inside " + my_number);
};

timesTwo(5);
console.log("outside " + my_number);
```

In the third example, `timesTwo` accepts a parameter and is using the variable `my_number` to keep track of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

In the function definition you specify the `my_number` parameter which introduces a new local variable into the scope of the function.

This will shadow the outer `my_number` so that any reference to *my_number* within the function body will refer to the incoming parameter rather than the outer *my_number* variable.